# How to get routing path in js file

Tags: php, jquery, mongodb, symfony

I have a new.html.twig,I am using few ajax calls on this page on changes events of drop down.

So I have created a septate js file called new.js and keep my all JavaScript code inside this file, instead to write it on same view file.

But here in this js file I am unable to access the routing path which is call a ajax request. on change event.

```
===========New.twig.html=====================
    include(new.js);
    <select><name='a' onchange="setLabel('123')"></select>
    ============new.js.=============        
    function setLabel(voucherTypeID) {           
    queryString = "voucherTypeID=" + voucherTypeID;
    $('#loading-image').show();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{path('vouchergeneration_getLedgers')}}", //THIS PATH How TO GET
    data: queryString,
    cache: "false",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data){
    });
```

So here I am not able to access the URL Path, while it was accessible in twig file before. Please guide me how to fix this. I do not want to use anykind of Bundle for this simple work.. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

There is very simple bundle for this simple work [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)

Once this bundle is enabled you only need to do

```
Routing.generate('my_route_to_expose', { id: 10 }); // will result in
/foo/10/bar

Routing.generate('my_route_to_expose', { id: 10, foo: "bar" }); //
will result in /foo/10/bar?foo=bar

$.get(Routing.generate('my_route_to_expose', { id: 10, foo: "bar" }));
// will call /foo/10/bar?foo=bar

Routing.generate('my_route_to_expose_with_defaults'); // will result
in /blog/1

Routing.generate('my_route_to_expose_with_defaults', { id: 2 }); //
will result in /blog/2

Routing.generate('my_route_to_expose_with_defaults', { foo: "bar" });
// will result in /blog/1?foo=bar

Routing.generate('my_route_to_expose_with_defaults', { id: 2, foo:
"bar" }); // will result in /blog/2?foo=bar
```

**EDIT:**
Of course you can do it without bundle (which I don't think is a good idea). In that case I would advice set your routes in controller's action and set use it in twig template to set js variable. Something like:

**Controller:**

```
public function indexAction()
{
    return array('yourRoute' => $router->generate('yourRoutName'));
}
```

**your template:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var yourRoute = '{{yourRoute}}';
</script>
```

**your js:**

```
(...)
url: yourRoute,
(...)
```

Comment: Actually I am not using any kind of bundle till now in my application. So Please can you tell me the some another way to fix this out.. Without FOS Routing Bundle

Comment: check my edit, but I don't see point in avoiding bundles. ``Twig``, ``Doctrine`` etc - these are all bundles so you are using it either way. Why should you reinvent the wheel?

Comment: There's no real advantage to generating the route in the controller and passing it to Twig. You can use the path() and url() functions in Twig for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to embed an URL and get it with your JS, you could do something like the following:

```
// HTML/Twig
<html data-my-route="{{ path('vouchergeneration_getLedgers') }}">
    ...
</html>
```

Then in your JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $('html').attr('data-my-route'),
    data: queryString,
    cache: "false",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data){
});
```

It avoids having global variable, and you can use as many data-attribute as you want.

Comment: Can I use this like: <div data-my-route = "{{path('vouchergeneration_getLedgers') }}"></div> <div data-my-route1 = "{{path('vouchergeneration_getLedgers1') }}"></div>  Because I have 5-6 ajax call on the same twig for different purpose. Instead writing it <html></html> we can write one <html> tag in a twig file only..

Comment: You could add as many data-attribute as you want ;) as in 
`<html data-ledger-one="{{path('vouchergeneration_getLedgers') }}" data-ledget-two="{{path('vouchergeneration_getLedgers2') }}">..</html>`. Do you get it? By the way, I would suggest you to have only one route which filter the result according to parameters, if possible :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fetch then you can get the url of the post by using data.url:

```
  fetch('/check', {
      method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(qrinfo)
    })
    .then((data) => {
      let url = data.url;
      if(url.includes('/leave.html')) {
        window.location.replace('/leave.html');

      }
      else {
        console.log("Page not changed.");
      }
      console.log('Success:', data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
```

You can check if the path name is included in the url instead by using `.includes()` so changing ports won't be an issue.